# Is L'Hopital a good idea in this case?

Tags: limits, continuity

> Find $a$ and $b$ so that function $f$ is continuous.
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcc}
>  \frac{\sin(3x)(e^{ax}-1)}{2x^3} &:&x<0 \\
> ax^2+3x+b &:& 0\le x <1\\
> \frac{\tan^2(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} &:&x\ge1
> \end{array}
> \right.
> \end{eqnarray*}

Well, I've been thinking on this and no way except L'Hôpital's rule has come to my mind, and this way takes a while to solve. Is there any better way?

Comment: Did you think about Taylor series ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sin(3x)}{x}\frac{e^{ax}-1}{x}
$$
is finite. But you still have another $x$ at the denominator, so the limit is infinite unless…

$$
\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{\tan(x-1)}{x-1}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\tan t}{t}=…
$$

Comment: I would say "unless.... $\;a=0\;$ ", but then also $\;b=0\;$ and ...etc .

Comment: a must be 0, that's ok but why b=0?

Comment: tan part's limit will be 1 so $ lim ax^2+3x+b$ when x-->1 from left should be 1 too.

Comment: @AliSeyfi What's $f(0)$?

Comment: @egreg got it. tnx

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:
Knowing 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\cos x\frac{\tan x}{x}=1,$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1,$$

L'Hospital is unnecessary.